# flex item overflows container due to long word even after using word-wrap

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

```css
.parent{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  padding:1em;
  background-color:red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.child1{
  background-color:mistyrose;
  padding:1em;
}

.child2{
  background-color:powderblue;
  padding:.5em;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  max-width:500px;
}
.child3{
  background-color:powderblue;
  padding:.5em;
  word-wrap:break-word;

}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child1">
   question
 </div>
  <div class="child2">
      somethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomething
    
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
    question
  </div>
  <div class="child3">
   somethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomething
  </div>
</div>
```

The main issue with the above code is ,`child3` overflows but if I give a `max-width` in `child2`it will not overflow the `parent`. In both cases I used   `word-wrap: break-word;`

**You can check the code here**   http://jsfiddle.net/vbj10x4k/

I need to know why it happens and how to solve it without using `max-width/width` to fixed pixel values.**I need it to be responsive**.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Instead of setting a max-width for your flex item, use a min-width declaration.

By default, if no min-width is set, the item's content min-width is assumed and the flex item's width will never be smaller. By setting a min-width of e.g. 40%, the item will shrink to at most 40% of the flex parent.

```
.child2, .child3 {
  min-width: 40%;
}
```

```css
.parent{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  padding:1em;
  background-color:red;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.child1{
  background-color:mistyrose;
  padding:1em;
}
.child2{
  background-color:powderblue;
  padding:.5em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  min-width: 40%;
}
.child3{
  background-color:lightyellow;
  padding:.5em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  min-width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1">
    question
  </div>
  <div class="child2">
   somethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomethingsomething

  </div>
  <div class="child3">
    Works well with long URLs: <a href="#"> https://thisisadamnlongurlcontainingneitherhyphensoradditionalperiods.com</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

See the code snippet above or the external demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vbj10x4k/5/

Comment: You can also set it to something very small like `min-width: 1%;` on the element with `word-wrap: break-word;` and  it works.

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking for the solution for a while. But I don't get why `min-width` keeps the inbox item from exceeding the container size...

Comment: Just a quick note: the `word-wrap` property has been replaced by `overflow-wrap` in modern browsers. (I've updated the answer to use both properties.) See https://caniuse.com/#search=overflow-wrap

Comment: Yes, it works of course (just like adriaan's 1%). The issue with very small values is that in some cases the flex child will actually become that small and will not be readable at all. By setting a reasonable min-width, this can be avoided.

Answer (score 49):

Instead of `word-wrap:break-word` use `word-break:break-all`

**CSS**

```
.child1{
  background-color:mistyrose;
  padding:1em;
  word-break:break-all;
}
.child2{
  background-color:powderblue;
  padding:.5em;
  max-width:500px;
  word-break:break-all;
}
.child3{
  background-color:powderblue;
  padding:.5em;
  word-break:break-all;

}
```

here is the working fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/yudi/vbj10x4k/3/

Comment: This solution will even break the word "question" in child1 elements which is probably not intended. And you are still using a fixed max-width which doesn't go well with a responsive design.

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work, it's just too much. Just take a look at the demo and the `.child1` elements. The word "question" is split into lines for each character. I just assume this is not intended. Also, `.child2` still has a maximum width set which will break your layout in devices with screen sizes below that value.

Comment: because word wrap works when there is spaces between words of there is no space between words you should use word break

Comment: Out of all solutions I've seen, such as setting `min-width: 0`, this is the only one that worked for me. Thanks

Comment: word-break: break-word; is what most people actually want. it will break words only when they're too long. otherwise it breaks them no matter what.

Answer (score 16):

I am using a combination like this and it works for me on Chrome, Safari, and Firefox.

```
.myOverflowableText {
  word-break: break-word; /* Chrome, Safari */
  overflow-wrap: anywhere; /* Firefox */
}
```

This site says word-break is supported on Chrome & Safari https://caniuse.com/#feat=word-break.

But I found that Firefox's solution should be `overflow-wrap: anywhere` on this site: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap

I'm not sure about IE yet... Maybe `word-wrap: break-word;` works on IE?

My goal is this:

```
Hello this is some |
text. I am writing |
some text.         |
Especially long    |
words go to the    |
next line like     |
this. This is a    |
veryveryveryveryve |
ryveryverylongword |
.                  |
```

Answer (score 7):

Adding `min-w-0` via tailwind fixed this for me.

Comment: While this helps, this answer is platform-specific. As this question neither references nor is tagged with Tailwind, the OP is most likely not using it. [`min-w-0` is just an abstraction for the CSS `min-width: 0px;`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/min-width).

Comment: Well anyone who sees my answer who is using Tailwind can utilize this information. This came up in the top search result of Google for `flex box break word` when I was looking for a solution. This happens in other threads as well, for example I was looking up MySQL column types for latitude/longitude and someone posted a Laravel migration, which helped me since I was using Laravel anyways. Just because this question is platform specific doesn't mean it won't help people who may not be using the specific platform it applies to.

Comment: @bastinald As a Tailwind user myself, I happen to be one of those people who was appreciative of the platform-specific answer. Though, @Nat Riddle has a point that it should probably be secondary to the "vanilla CSS" answer, i.e. "Use `min-width: 0px;` (or `min-w-0` for Tailwind users out there)". Thanks to you both!

Answer (score -7):

Thanks to the Gaurav Aggarwal's answer, I've been able to solve the same kind of issue by using the CSS property:

```
word-break: break-word
```